# Hive Explode the Array of Struct key: value:

Tags: sql, arrays, hive, hiveql, explode

This is the below Hive Table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SampleTable
(
USER_ID string,
DETAIL_DATA array<struct<key:string,value:string>>
)
```

And this is the data in the above table-

```
11111    [{"key":"client_status","value":"ACTIVE"},{"key":"name","value":"Jane Doe"}]
```

Is there any way I can get the below output using HiveQL?

```
  **client_status**  |   **name**
  -------------------+----------------
         ACTIVE         Jane Doe
```

I tried use *explode()* but I get result like that:

```
SELECT details
FROM sample_table
lateral view explode(DETAIL_DATA) exploded_table as details;


               **details** 
-------------------------------------------+
   {"key":"client_status","value":"ACTIVE"}        
 ------------------------------------------+
     {"key":"name","value":"Jane Doe"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `laterral view [outer] inline` to get struct elements already etracted and use conditional aggregation to get values corresponting to some keys grouped in single row, use group_by user_id.

Demo:

```
with sample_table as (--This is your data example
select '11111' USER_ID,
array(named_struct('key','client_status','value','ACTIVE'),named_struct('key','name','value','Jane Doe')) DETAIL_DATA
)

SELECT max(case when e.key='name' then e.value end) as name, 
       max(case when e.key='client_status' then e.value end) as status
FROM sample_table
lateral view inline(DETAIL_DATA) e as key, value
group by USER_ID
```

Result:

```
    name    status  
------------------------
Jane Doe    ACTIVE
```

If you can guarantee the order of structs in array (one with status comes first always), you can address nested elements dirctly

```
SELECT detail_data[0].value as client_status,
       detail_data[1].value as name
 from sample_table
```

One more approach, if you do not know the order in array, but array is of size=2, CASE expressions without explode will give better performance:

```
SELECT case when DETAIL_DATA[0].key='name' then DETAIL_DATA[0].value else  DETAIL_DATA[1].value end as name, 
       case when DETAIL_DATA[0].key='client_status' then DETAIL_DATA[0].value else  DETAIL_DATA[1].value end as status
FROM sample_table
```